# how to set a NumPy MaskedArray's mask to False?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a MaskedArray with a mask that has all False values in the mask, I want to collapse it into a single boolean False value.  For example:

```
    >>> import numpy.ma as npma
    >>> ma = npma.MaskedArray([1,2,3], mask=[False, False, False])
    >>> ma
    masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
         mask=[False, False, False],
   fill_value=999999)
   >>> ma.mask = npma.nomask
   >>> ma
   masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
         mask=[False, False, False],
   fill_value=999999)
   >>> mas.mask = False
   >>> ma
   masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
         mask=[False, False, False],
   fill_value=999999)
```

No matter what I've tried, I can't get an already-created MaskedArray to go back to having just a single False value instead of an array of False values.  The only work around I've found is to create a new MaskedArray from the existing MaskedArray's data property, and leave out the mask argument.  Note how mask is now just False, which is what I want.

```
   >>> ma = npma.MaskedArray(ma.data)
   >>> ma
   masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
         mask=False,
   fill_value=999999)
```

Is there a way to set the mask property to False?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your usecase? If your mask stays that way, you don't really need a masked array. If it doesn't, you just wasted a bunch of cycles only to waste more re-expanding into a full mask...

Comment: Good question.  My usecase involves mostly storing and representing datasets, as opposed to needing to do a bunch of calculations using the masks.  While having a boolean array of False values is technically correct, for reasons specific to a library I am developing, I wanted the ability to easily "shrink" the mask, like the answer below shows how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`m.shrink_mask()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.shrink_mask.html) after you set the mask:

```
>>> m
masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=999999)
       
>>> m.mask = False
masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
             mask=[False, False, False],
       fill_value=999999)

>>> m.shrink_mask()  # <-------------- Here
>>> m
masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=999999)
```